# What is the best way to handle all SPItem's on SharePoint web Application level?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

What is the best way to handle all the newly added documents and items to the SharePoint lists and Document Libraries on Share Point Web Application Level.

My case is that I want to do some insertions to database when any new document or item added.

#### note:

1- The Site Collections , Web or Sub Sites and Lists are **not** predefined.

2- I need to apply the handlers on both existing and new Document Libraries and lists.

#### my current options are:

1- Analyze Share Point Log.

2- Add Event Recievers to all SPLists.

Any Advices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use event receivers extensively on our Sharepoint system. They are very reliable and easy to write. [You can register an event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475328.aspx) using a feature scoped at the site level, so it will fire for all SPListItem events (adding, updating, deleting, etc) that occur within that site collection for the list type you specify.

Comment: How can I register event handlers to the existing lists , is there an easy way rather than looping on the whole site lists?